# Roll up and Cube operator in access (Summary Queries)

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2007

Are there any equivalents to the Rollup and Cube operators in Access? If not, how can I write subtotal and grand total (summary data) queries in Access?

I have written :

```
SELECT a,b FROM dumy
UNION ALL select a,sum(b) from dumy
group by a ;
```

The output is like the image below, or something similar to that,

[image]

But the expected result is this:

[image]

Comment: A query is not the place to have both data and totals, although it is possible. What is the problem that you hope to solve with this approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Crosstab](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304348) queries. This will produce one row:

```
TRANSFORM Count(b.ID) AS [Count]
SELECT "BASE" AS SomeName, Count(b.ID) AS Total
FROM ATable AS b
WHERE Something='Text'
GROUP BY "BASE"
PIVOT AFieldName;
```

Answer (score 0):

It just requires sorting.

```
Select T.Total
  , T.a
  , T.b
From (
   SELECT '' as Label
     , a 
     ,b 
   FROM dumy 
   UNION ALL 
  select 'Total' as Label
    , a
    ,sum(b) 
  from dumy 
  group by a 
) as T
Order By T.a, T.Total;
```